# printing the char variable value using %d

Tags: c, types

I was trying to get into c programming, but in a question a get stuck, please explain this.

```
 int main()
{
 char c = 255;
 c=c+10;
 printf("%d",c);
 return 0;
 }
```

the output it gave is

```
> 9
```

**kindly explain this to me.**

Comment: @Biffen my bad wrong research i suppose i will remove the comment

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value of a char is `255`.

By adding `10` to that number you get `265`.

Because that value is not a suitable value for a char it will do `265 % 256` resulting `9`

That's why your result is `9`

Comment: The modulo reasoning is not quite correct. You don't use module 255 but module 256.

Comment: Oh yeah because there are 256 values possible (0 to 255). You're right

Comment: If the `char` is `signed` then it is undefined behaviour.